# Way to pick random addresses from dynamic ranges in SV constraints

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

I have a requirement to pick random addresses from a set of predefined ranges in Systemverilog

```
program test;

int unsigned q[$], rSz;
typedef struct {
  int unsigned from, till;
} range_t;

initial begin
    range_t ranges[$];

    ranges.push_back('{from: 'h10, till: 'h1F});
    ranges.push_back('{from: 'h30, till: 'h3F});
    ranges.push_back('{from: 'h50, till: 'h5F});

    rSz = ranges.size();
    $displayh(rSz, ranges);

    repeat (10) begin
        std::randomize(q) with {
            q.size() inside {[4:8]};
            foreach (q[i]) {
                q[i] inside {[ranges[0].from: ranges[0].till]} ||
                q[i] inside {[ranges[1].from: ranges[1].till]} ||
                q[i] inside {[ranges[2].from: ranges[2].till]} ;
            }
        };
        $displayh(q);
    end
end

endprogram : test
```

It works fine if I have a fixed number of ranges that I can hard-code.
But the number of ranges itself is dynamic, I can not hard-code the ranges as in the `foreach` loop.

I can't use a `nested foreach` as the statements in the inner loop will be treated as individual constraints and fail with each other as the ranges are non-overlapping.

All I could come up with is something like below where I use the ranges in order and then shuffle at the end.

```
program test;

int unsigned q[$], rSz;
typedef struct {
  int unsigned from, till;
} range_t;

initial begin
    range_t ranges[$];
    ranges.push_back('{from: 'h10, till: 'h1F});
    ranges.push_back('{from: 'h30, till: 'h3F});
    ranges.push_back('{from: 'h50, till: 'h5F});

    rSz = ranges.size();
    $displayh(rSz, ranges);

    repeat (10) begin
        std::randomize(q) with {
            q.size() inside {[4:8]};
            foreach (q[i]) {
                q[i] inside {[ranges[i % rSz].from: ranges[i % rSz].till]};
            }
        };
        q.shuffle();
        $displayh(q);
    end
end

endprogram : test
```

Is there a better way of doing this in general?

I am looking for something like `foreach-or` where all lines in loop are `or-ed` instead of `and-ed` - if that explains the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people are familiar with the `sum()` array reduction method, but there are also `or()`, `and()`, and `xor()` reduction methods as well.

```
module test;
  int unsigned q[$], rSz;
  typedef struct {
    int unsigned from, till;
  } range_t;
  
  initial begin
    range_t ranges[$];

    ranges.push_back('{from: 'h10, till: 'h1F});
    ranges.push_back('{from: 'h30, till: 'h3F});
    ranges.push_back('{from: 'h50, till: 'h5F});

    rSz = ranges.size();
    $displayh(rSz,, ranges);

    repeat (10) begin
      assert(std::randomize(q) with {
        q.size() inside {[4:8]};
        foreach (q[i]) 
          ranges.or(range) with (q[i] inside {[range.from: range.till]});
      });
      $displayh(q);
    end
  end
endmodule: test
```

See section *7.12.3 Array reduction methods* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595).

Comment: Awesome dave_59. Works like a charm and thanks for giving me a new perspective that is always forgoten